# Index: 2, Size: 2, Index: 1, Size: 1 Error in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am observing very strange error in my coldfusion application. This error appears sometime and after page refresh it gone away. This error not tied to any particular page within my application. It appears randomly in any page.Please suggest me how to correct it.

**Note: It appears sometime not always.** 
**Coldfusion server: 10.8
Web Server: IIS 7
OS : Window 7**

Stack Trace information

```
The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Index: 2, Size: 2

Resources:

    Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
    Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.

Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Remote Address      127.0.0.1
Referrer    http://mysite.url/index.cfm?action=users&displayMode=users&tagID=0&cfid=151062&cftoken=23d66b7903e3662d-80DF390F-0C45-8090-0A2DF20C76367E1F
Date/Time       05-Apr-13 07:26 PM
Stack Trace


java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at coldfusion.monitor.util.MonitorList.add(MonitorList.java:133)
    at coldfusion.monitor.memory.SessionMemoryMonitor.record(SessionMemoryMonitor.java:68)
    at coldfusion.monitor.memory.SessionMemoryMonitor.record(SessionMemoryMonitor.java:53)
    at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryMonitor.record(MemoryMonitor.java:279)
    at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryRequestEventHandler.onRequestComplete(MemoryRequestEventHandler.java:23)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.RequestMonitorEventProcessor.onRequestComplete(RequestMonitorEventProcessor.java:283)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Code from comments

```
<cfset siteArray = ArrayNew (1)>
<cfloop query="GetSites">
    <cfset obj = StructNew ()>
    <cfset obj.ID = GetSites.ID>
    <cfset obj.Title = GetSites.Title>
    <cfset obj.SiteURL = GetSites.SiteURL>
    <cfset obj.LayoutID = GetSites.LayoutID>
    <cfset t = ArrayAppend (siteArray, obj)>
    <cfset tokenName = obj.SiteURL> 
    <cfset tokenName = Replace (tokenName, ".", "", "ALL")>
    <cfset tokenName = Replace (tokenName, "-", "", "ALL")>
    <cfset tokenName = "URL_#tokenName#">
    <cfset "Application.#tokenName#" = ArrayLen (siteArray)>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: do you have an arraylist command possibly in your application.cfc, .cfm or in another file that gets executed throughout your site?

Comment: at one page i have this piece of code 
<cfset siteArray = ArrayNew (1)>
 
 <cfloop query="GetSites">
  <cfset obj = StructNew ()>
  <cfset obj.ID = GetSites.ID>
  <cfset obj.Title = GetSites.Title>
  <cfset obj.SiteURL = GetSites.SiteURL>
  <cfset obj.LayoutID = GetSites.LayoutID>
  
  <cfset t = ArrayAppend (siteArray, obj)>
  <cfset tokenName = obj.SiteURL>
  <cfset tokenName = Replace (tokenName, ".", "_", "ALL")>
  <cfset tokenName = Replace (tokenName, "-", "_", "ALL")>
  <cfset tokenName = "URL_#tokenName#">
  <cfset "Application.#tokenName#" = ArrayLen (siteArray)>
 </cfloop>

Comment: I would try dumping out all the values of all the values that you use in your array functions.  Its hard to pinpoint, but your error indicates an issue with possibly some of the data that your sending to an array function.  Thats probably the most information I can provide.

Comment: The strange part is it does not appear always. It appears sometime and when i refresh it the error gone away.

Comment: I don't see where the code in your comment could be generating the error you're getting.

Comment: another thing to note - when you use `<cflocation>` I would highly recommend not using `addtoken="true"` (appears that's being used based on the referer in your code)

Comment: Ok, I have to check in my code whether I have used it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like monitoring is causing this.  I've been monitoring the server this afternoon and left monitoring "on". Turning off monitoring resolves this weird issue :-)

Found the answer here :

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/885925?start=0&tstart=0